# jquery mobile breaks scroll script

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am using the following code to force the div to be fixed on the x axis but scroll on the y:

```
var leftOffset = parseInt($("#header").css('left'));
$(window).scroll(function(){
$('#header').css({
    'left': $(this).scrollLeft() + leftOffset
});
});
```

You can see the fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/EzXub/263/

However when I add jquery mobile link in the head section of my page:

It stops the script I was using from working and the div doesn't fix when scrolling horizontally.

Is there something in this jquery mobile that is breaking it and is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted (question seems ok to me) - however, when i visit your fiddle and then check the mobile option all is well (http://jsfiddle.net/EzXub/1480/) - the mobile option hides the fiddler menu though

Comment: Im not sure either :/  I have added this linked version:
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js
I might try it with the 1.0.1 version that is shown in the fiddle. Maybe that is the reason?

Comment: that one works for me too.. O_o

Comment: just had a quick check and using 1.0.1 works. When I use the 1.4.2 it stops working for some reason

Comment: Thats strange if 1.4.2 is working for you :/

Comment: I can only really recommend to check the console of the output panel to see if there are any errors. Sorry i couldn't help more.

Comment: jQM page has `overflow-x` set to `hidden`, it doesn't scroll horizontally. Edit: try this on your mobile device http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/hjt4m2gp/

Comment: the same with me, but breaks vertical scrolling.. on my div overflow scroll